# Rendering to arbitrary layout files in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering, ruby-on-rails-3

How would I go about rendering with an arbitrary layout file in my Rails 3 application?

Reading 2.2.4 Rendering an Arbitrary File in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render tells me this is possible for files (just pass a `:file` option to the `render` call that starts with a leading slash.

However in Rails 3.0.1 this does *not* work for the `:layout` option, which is what I wanted: render an arbitrary file to an arbitrary layout.

Comment: What's the purpose of using arbitrary file as a layout?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, you say it does work for the :layout option, and then say thats what you wanted. Did you mean doesn't work?

Comment: Not sure what an arbitrary layout file is, please clarify.

Comment: I think arbitrary layout file is a layout file that is located somewhere else than in `/app/views/layouts/` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
render :template => '/absolute/path/to/template'
```

Keep in mind that, unless you have `<%= yield %>` in that document, nothing will render other than that file's contents. Can I ask why you are doing this? If you are trying to have the user download a file or view a file, this is not the best way...

Comment: Does this work? Is it because of the first slash? Too lazy to check it myself.. :)

Comment: Well, I know that :D. I didn't spot anything in the docs regarding templates outside the templates folder. Maybe it's a dark plan for brainwashing everyone to use RAILS CONVENTIONS (which is not a bad thing).

Comment: @Heikki: The ultimate point is to let the user upload and use his own layout files, which I store in different places. This has to be safeguarded against ruby code injection attacks, which I still have to figure out if its even possible. In the meantime, I manage the files and keep them somewhere different from app/views/layouts. Any smarter alternatives?

Comment: why not just have customizeable areas of your template? like a bunch of different themes and options to choose from. it could be simple like twitter or more complex like magento.

Comment: Maybe related: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.0/AbstractController/ViewPaths/ClassMethods/append_view_path

Comment: @Joao Tavora: Shopify and some other places use liquid for this, and I think I read somewhere they store their templates in the database. This might be a wise option if you can use caching wisely and not drown your DB.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing this is to simply **add "layouts" somewhere in the path to the layout**. It seems ridiculous, but Rails will only add the "layouts/" prefix if it isn't already in the path.

```
# rails/lib/abstract_controller/layouts.rb:268
# out of context, but here in all it's glory
_prefix = "layouts" unless _implied_layout_name =~ /\blayouts/
```

Just to make sure I'm clear here, here's an example:

```
# your layout at app/themes/foobar/layouts/foobar.html.erb
layout Rails.root.join('app/themes/foobar/layouts/foobar').to_s
        #=> renders /path/to/your/app/themes/foobar/layouts/foobar.html.erb
```

Comment: Very nice @coreyward! And I agree, "It seems ridiculous". Make your paths MUST end in "layouts/".